# How we can check that scrollbar is scrollable or not in selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium

I have to check that horizontal scroll bar is scrollable or not. I tried by doing check element is **displayed** or not which comes after horizontal scroll using 
Javascript `scrollIntoView` but how it can make sure that scrollbar is working.

Because scroll bar position not changing `scrollIntoView` only scrolling the element and making as displayed on the screen. But scroll bar not scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Try below options to scroll horizontally :

```
// scroll at a particular element

WebElement e1 =

driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//input [@id=’ElementID’]”));

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(“arguments[0].scrollIntoView();”, e1);

Where ‘e1’ is the locator where you want to scroll.

// scroll at a particular coordinate,.  

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(“window.scrollBy(200,300)”);



// scroll horizontally in the right direction.
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(“window.scrollBy(2000,0)”);

// scroll horizontally in the left direction.
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(“window.scrollBy(-2000,0)”);
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is simple- first, try to move the scrollbar bar to either side and check whether it's actually moved or not.

```
//scrol 1px to the left
$(document).scrollLeft(1);

if($(document).scrollLeft() != 0){
   //there's a scroll bar
}else{
   //there's no scrollbar
}
//scroll back to original location
$(document).scrollLeft(0);
```

Let's convert it to a Java method and use it in your script.

```
    /**
     * 
     * @param js reference to JavascriptExecutor
     * @param element is a string of locator (i.e. #scroll > span etc.)
     * @return true if scrollbar is scrollable
     */
    boolean testScrollBar(JavascriptExecutor js, String element){
        String jq = String.format("return $('%s').scrollLeft()", element);
        String jq1 = String.format("$('%s').scrollLeft(1)", element);
        String jq2 = String.format("$('%s').scrollLeft(0)", element);

        System.err.println("Test1: "+js.executeScript(jq));

        js.executeScript(jq1);

        Long currentPos =  (Long)js.executeScript(jq);

        System.err.println("Test2: " + currentPos);

        js.executeScript(jq2);

        return currentPos != 0;
    }
```

I hope it helps you.